# Can't save http result to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, http-get

I have a json-file defined and I am trying to load in one of my controllers. I am using a factory to fetch the data:

```
.factory('myService', function($http) {

  var all_data = [];

    return {
      getAllData: function(){
        return $http.get('js/data/all_data.json').then(function(data) {
          all_data  = data;
          return all_data ;
      });
        }
    }
})
```

Later in my controller I call `getAllData()` in a `loadData()`-function:

```
.controller('QuizCtrl',['$scope','$state','$http','myService',function($scope,$state,$http,myService){

    // $scope.myData = []; <-- this makes the app freeze and not respond anymore
    $scope.loadData = function(){
      myService.getAllData().then(function(all_data){
          $scope.myData = all_data.data.all_data;
          alert($scope.myData);
      });
    }

    $scope.loadData();
    $scope.another_var = $scope.myData;

}])
```

As you can see first of all I am also calling `loadData()`. While debugging inside the function (see `alert()`) I can clearly see how the json has been loaded and applied to the `$scope.myData` variable.

Once I try to assign the variable to another variable (see `$scope.another_var`) myData is 'undefined'.

What I tried was defining `$scope.myData` before the `$scope.loadData()` call (see comment in code). Unfortunately, this simple variable declaration makes my app freeze completely. I have not found the reason for this yet. Also, I am not sure if it is related to my overall problem.

So what have I missed? Why am I not able to store my "http get" result in my controller's `$scope`?

**EDIT**: So in my case, I need the data to be there before the current Controller is even used. Would it be a legit option to put all the code which is executed within the controller into the `.then`-chain of the promise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your HTTP request is an asyncronous function while the assignment  `$scope.another_var = $scope.myData;` is syncronous.

Basically what's going on is that when your `QuizCtrl` controller is loaded, it finishes the statement `$scope.another_var = $scope.myData;` before it finishes the http request of `getAllData()`. What you've got is a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

If you want to change the value of `another_var` move it within your async callback:

```
$scope.loadData = function(){
      myService.getAllData().then(function(all_data){
          $scope.myData = all_data.data.all_data;
          alert($scope.myData);

          // because now $scope.myData is available this assignment will work:
          $scope.another_var = $scope.myData;
      });
    }

$scope.loadData();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to udpate a different value based on the value that is already on scope, you could observe the value for changes and update accordingly.

here is what you could do.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope", "sampleService",
  function($scope, sampleService) {

    sampleService.sampleMethod(1).then(function(value) {
      $scope.value = value;
      $scope.$digest();
    }, function(error) {});

    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return $scope.value;
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
      //Default Value when the dependant value is not available
      newValue = newValue || 0;
      $scope.myNewValue = newValue * 10;
    });

  }
]);

app.service("sampleService", function() {
  this.sampleMethod = function(value) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        value = value * 2;
        resolve(value);
      }, 1000);
    });
    return promise;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <div>Value: {{value}}</div>
    <div>Cloned Value : {{myNewValue}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a promiss `$q`

take this method for instance:

```
.factory('myService', function($http,$q) {
    var all_data = [];
    return {
        getAllData: function () {
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http.get('js/data/all_data.json')
                .success(function (response) {
                    d.resolve(response);
                });
            return d.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the issue @Marc Rassmussen

Comment: @Käsebrot Could you post a fiddle or something similar then il gladly look it over and make it work. Im 100% certain it has something to do with promiss